# Preserve special characters in PHP string

Tags: php, special-characters

I have a HTML form that posts to PHP. I get a bunch of variables in PHP like for example:

```
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
```

etcetera. Later on, these variables are printed to a PDF file I'm generating with PHP.

However, many times the form is submitted with 'special characters' like ë, é, ü, etcetera. I want to preserve those characters. At this moment, those characters are printed to the PDF as:

```
Ã© Ã«
```

How do I preserve the accented characters?

Comment: Every character is special in its own way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure character encoding is correct:

- The form should be on a page that has a charset of UTF-8
- You may need to call `utf8_encode` or `utf8_decode`, based on the values you get on the server
- Double-check that the PDF's character encoding is UTF-8.

Comment: Great, that solved it! The page the form was on was indeed UTF-8. I had to wrap the posted data in utf8_decode like so: `$firstname = utf8_decode($_POST['firstname']);` and that fixed it. Thanks!